# load a page within a div using ajax and after submit load in the same div

Tags: ajax, jsp, html

i have a homepage with hyperlinks and a div tag id="contentarea" in which the results of this hyperlinks are loaded.Now on clicking a link Search,**search.jsp** loads which contains a submit button and the **form action="search.jsp".** search.jsp contains some dropdown lists used to search.What i wish is to show the results in the same div id="contentarea" below the dropdownlists.
I don't know jQuery and would like to avoid it,plz.
For dynamic ajax loading of pages in div i am using code provided 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

Comment: That link has your specific example, does it not work?

Comment: yes.it does.but not the submit button part.that's the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#contentarea").load("search.jsp");
```

Comment: thanx for the prompt reply.I had requested to avoid jquery :-P
if this is the only way to do it, plz tell me where do i write this code????
and could you plz provide similar example links  to help me?? thank u agn.

Comment: its very simple .why you avoid that.

Comment: ok.i must try it then.but where should i put this code that u have given??

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js download this plugin and  put in one folder of your project .Ex. We put image file.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="your_folder_name/jquery.min.js"></script> add this tag into jsp after the <head> start

Comment: to make it easy for me,
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form action="search.jsp" method=post>
    //code for dropdown lists
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val" id="val" value="0">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
     <%    
      if(request.getParameter("val")!=null)
       {
         //code to show the result
       }
//where should i put -$("#contentarea").load("search.jsp");

Comment: <html> 
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="your_folder_name/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contentarea").load("search.jsp");
  });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="search.jsp" method=post> 
 //code for dropdown lists 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH" /> 
 <input type="hidden" name="val" id="val" value="0"> 
</form>